# When using Twilio, how can I make a call from a Phone to a Browser?

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to make a call from a phone to a browser but can't seem to make it work.

I think I need to add a `client` parameter to the call but I can't find any answers in the documentation on how to do this.

I am using the [PHP TWIML generator](https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/twiml.html#dial).

```
public function outboundCallResponse()
{
    $this->response->say('Please wait while we connect your call.');

    $dial = $this->response->dial(null, ['callerId' => '+1##########']);
    $dial->client('client-name'); // how do I make this part work?
    $dial->number('+1##########');

    return $this->response;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio.

If I were you, I'd take a look through [this tutorial on how to set up an app with Twilio Client and PHP](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client) from the Twilio "How to" section.

If you want to jump straight to the section on receiving calls, [take a look here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/incoming-calls).

Comment: Thanks I apparently already had it working, it just wasn't working for me at that time apparently for no reason. I blame caching.